# Python route finder for aviation

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, math, matplotlib-basemap

I made an app that besides all other things try to find a valid route between 2 airports.
I have all the required data in a sqlite3 database witch i query and plot in a basemap embeded in PyQt5 with signals live.
My problem is i can't find the algorithm to make all possible variations(with disqualify some, as all possibilies are enormous ) and store them to output the final valid routes.
Dijkstra's algorithm i think can't implemented as any time a route can reach a dead end.

My main problem is the algorithm and its implementation and not the data so don't hesitate and write any data required for any possible algorithm.

The algorith hints are:

1. I have a starting waypoint.
2. I find all routes that includes this starting point(disqualifying oposite headings)(each route have various waypoints).
3. Find next waypoint for each route.
4. Now this waypoint can be connected to other route and so on.
5. Routes then tested and disquilyfied by various variants or reaching dead ends.
6. Continue until you reach to the final(target waypoint).
7. Output the somehow stored route(s)

What i got so far with stack issues:

```
##finding base direction##
base_radians = math.atan2(self.dest_coord[0]-self.dep_coord[0], self.dest_coord[1]-self.dep_coord[1])
base_degrees = math.degrees(base_radians)
print(base_degrees)
if base_degrees < 0 :
    base_heading = 'W'
else:
    base_heading = 'E'
### finding all routes connected to first waypoint###
self.cursor.execute("select DISTINCT ats_ident,seq_num from dafif_ats where wpt1_ident = ? AND ats_icao = ? AND direction = ? ORDER BY ats_ident,seq_num ASC",('ATV','LGGG',base_heading))
sub_ats_idents = self.cursor.fetchall()
#### for each route find next waypoints###       
for i in sub_ats_idents:
    self.cursor.execute("select wpt1_ident,wpt2_ident from dafif_ats where ats_ident = ? and ats_icao = ?  and direction = ? and seq_num >= ? ORDER BY seq_num ASC",(i[0],'LGGG',base_heading,i[1]))
    each_wpt_combo = self.cursor.fetchall()
    #### for each next waypoint find possible routes###   
    for x in each_wpt_combo:
        self.cursor.execute("select DISTINCT ats_ident,seq_num from dafif_ats where wpt1_ident = ? AND ats_icao = ? AND direction = ? ORDER BY ats_ident,seq_num ASC",(x[0],'LGGG',base_heading))
        each_ats = self.cursor.fetchall()
        print(each_ats)
        #### for each subroute plot waypoints###   
        for z in each_ats:
            self.cursor.execute("select wpt1_dlon,wpt1_dlat,wpt2_dlon,wpt2_dlat from dafif_ats where wpt1_ident = ? AND ats_icao = ? AND direction = ? ORDER BY ats_ident,seq_num ASC",(x[0],'LGGG',base_heading))
            plot_var = self.cursor.fetchall()
            self.route_sender.emit(plot_var)
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

[image]

Any material or example to read will be super.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers , A* algorithm with hieristics is the solution for these kind of problems.